# Copy specific rows from One DataTable to another DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

Below is my code in which I am trying to copy 3 Columns "BATCH NUM", "QTY" and "PROD ID" from one to another. Problem is that "BATCH NUM", "QTY" are copied but "PROD ID" column is not copied.

```
var newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("BATCH NUM"))
              .Select(g =>
              {
                  var row = dt.NewRow();

                  row["BATCH NUM"] = g.Key;
                  row["QTY"] = g.Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("QTY")) + Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("BONUS")));
                  row["PROD ID"] = g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("PROD ID"));
                  return row;
              }).CopyToDataTable();
```

How can I copy "PROD ID" to DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Select` on `PROD ID` means you are trying to  store collection of string in a column which supports storing a string value. This will by default calls ToString method on a collection and results in System.Linq... string value in a column.

You want to use appropriate function to get all values in the column:

```
var newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("BATCH NUM"))
              .Select(g =>
              {
                  var row = dt.NewRow();

                  row["BATCH NUM"] = g.Key;
                  row["QTY"] = g.Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("QTY")) + Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("BONUS")));
                  row["PROD ID"] = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("PROD ID")).Distinct());
                  return row;
              }).CopyToDataTable();
```

[image]

Comment: I am grouping rows based on "BATCH NUM" so i want to get only those values of PROD ID.

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi In a string column you can only put a string vaue and not a collection of strings. You can use string.join to get all product ids instead. Check out my updated code.

Comment: I only want to get those values of PROD Id which are grouped by BATCH NUM. So which funtion should i use?

Comment: I have tried your code but it is not copying PROD ID column to DataTable

Comment: Yes i have tried your edited code but it is not copying PROD ID column to datatable

Comment: What do you see in the PROD ID column of the resulting datatable?

Comment: What if i want to remove this line .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("BATCH NUM")) because i want to ungroup them. Any idea?

Comment: @JahanzaibNiazi Sure you could, but make sure to change calls to aggregate functions (Sum) as well.